# Set variable range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function i am trying to create that basically clears the dropdown chose if dropdown in the previous cell is changed. I need to repeat this for many rows. currently it says my variable is not defined

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

For i = 17 To 1015
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D" & i)) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E" & i).ClearContents
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Kudos for `Option Explicit`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means you need to declare your variable `i` and specify a type before you can use it. You do this by `Dim i As Long`.

Additionally you will need a `Next i` to tell where the loop ends.

Also test `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` this only once (outside the loop).

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 17 To 1015
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D" & i)) Is Nothing Then
            Range("E" & i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Didn't test it but this should give the same result:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D17:D1015")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

This should be faster because it doesn't need to loop.

Comment: thank you so much i apprecite it. i knew i had to decalre "i" but i couldnt figure out the type to declare it as since i wanted a range kinda. thanks again!

Comment: what if i want to clear two rows? in the second one. How would you clear them?

Comment: What do you mean by 2 rows? which 2? The `i` and the one below `i+1`? This could be done with `Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=2).ClearContents`

Comment: im sorry i said rows instead of columns. but i just figured it out

Comment: Two columns would work like `Target.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Resize(ColumnSize:=2).ClearContents` for column E + F

Answer (score 2):

Type the following just below `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

```
Dim i as long
```

You need to define what i is before you can use it.